# How to bind dropdown values from Database through stored procedure in Strongly typed views in MVC..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed view as shown below:

```
  <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-10">

             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Text, "Drop");    @*Error Line*@

               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

With model Class DropdownCheck like below:

```
 public class DropdownCheck
 {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public String Test { get; set; }
 }
```

Basically, I don't want to hard-code values to view through list items,but wants to bind it from database through stored procedure.

So, For that I have controller like below

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Dropdown()
    {
        BusDataContext dtnew=new BusDataContext();
        ViewBag.Drop = new SelectList(dtnew.Bind_Dropdown().ToList(), "BusSrlNo", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

Also storing dropdown id,text in ViewBag as above.
where Bind_Dropdown() is like below

```
  public IEnumerable<DropdownValues> Bind_Dropdown()
   {
       var res = dt.Get_Bus_Dropdown().ToList();
       List<DropdownValues> drop = new List<DropdownValues>();

       for (var i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
       {
           DropdownValues name = new DropdownValues();
           name.drpbusid = Convert.ToInt32(res[i].BusSrlNo);
           name.drpbusname = Convert.ToString(res[i].Name);
           drop.Add(name);
       }
       return drop;
   }
```

where DropdownValues is a class like below:

```
   public class DropdownValues
{
    public int drpbusid { get; set; }
    public string drpbusname { get; set; }
}
```

Stored procedure returns dropdown value and Text as BusSrlNo and Name.
After doing all these stuff,getting error compilation like below:
:

> CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not
>   contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Change this line:

```
ViewBag.Drop = new SelectList(dtnew.Bind_Dropdown().ToList(), "BusSrlNo", "Name");
```

Into this:

```
ViewBag.Drop = new SelectList(dtnew.Bind_Dropdown().ToList(), "drpbusid", "drpbusname");
```

2)Change this line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Text, "Drop");
```

Into this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("anyName", ViewBag.Drop as SelectList)
```

I've replicated your error on my side and those are the only two changes I had to make to get it working.I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the signature you are trying to use (can .NET bind a value from a string like this?)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Text, "Drop");    @*Error Line*@
```

What happens if you switch this to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Text,
 ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Drop.Items))
```

Comment: No still I am getting-> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVC_DAL.DropdownValues]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.